# Possible reasons for symbol multiply defined other than 'extern'

Tags: c++, c, xcode, build, extern

Is there any reasons for 'symbol multiply defined' other than not having the declaration in .h, having it as 'extern', and have the implementation in .cpp?

I'm pretty sure that all my files follow the rule, but I'm getting an error message like this:

```
ld: lto: could not merge in /Users/zlw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wireless -  
amjmgyrircjezdhegioctszbcypz/Build/Intermediates/Wireless.build/Debug/Wireless.build/Objects 
normal/x86_64/qam.o because 'Linking globals named '_Z12SNRFromSNRdBd': symbol multiply 
defined!', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 3.3svn, from Apple Clang 5.0 (build 
500.2.76)' for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is the message means that all the troubles have something to do with 'qam.h' or 'qam.cpp'?

Is there any reasons other that 'extern' or is there any ways to see what is wrong with my code in Xcode?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it says that when you compile `qam.cpp`, you use a symbol named `_Z12SNRFromSNRdBd` (corresponding to `SNRFromSNRdB(double)`) which is defined more than once.

You should search for that function and who is implementing it.

Note : to convert from "mangled name" to human readable, you can use c++filt

```
bruce@lorien:~$ c++filt _Z12SNRFromSNRdBd
SNRFromSNRdB(double)
```

Comment: thanks! it's exactly the problem, I've defined the same function SNRFromSNRdB(double) twice in 2 different files.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can past your related code. That is clear.
I got the similar error I hope may help you. 
That is A Function I declare in a.h and implement in a.c, then I invoke in b.c. It does work. If I change the a.c and b.c to a.cpp and b.cpp, it is wrong.
The reason is CPP will change your function name for polymorphic.